# android output display

Tags: java, android

how to display the contents of a vector in android?do i need to use TextView?

Comment: It depends, what is it a vector of and what do you want it to look like?

Comment: its a string vector and i just want to display the string as a normal text on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate through the Vector elements using a  for loop using the Vector's elementAt(index) function and display them accordingly in the Text View. Simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you need to use a TextView to put text on the screen.